# Is it possible to attain diagonal scrolling using ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, custom-scrolling

I have a layout file having both ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView. And am able to scroll either in horizontal direction or vertical direction. Will it be possible to scroll diagonally?

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


           <Customview..../>

</HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```